# Quantum Scalar Field Theory with cubic and quartic interaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, feynman-diagrams, 1pi-effective-action

> If I have a scalar Lagrangian with and interaction term given by cubic and quartic terms (so a scalar theory + $φ^3+φ^4$ interaction), what are the possible divergent 1PI diagrams at one and two loops?

According to dimensional regularization, the divergence $D$ in this theory (and in 4 dimensions) is $D=4-E-V_3$, where E are the external lines, and $V_3$ are the three-point vertexes.
Should I draw any possible diagram with 3 or 4 lines meeting at a vertex plus external lines such that $D\geq0$?